# Stored procedure to add a row to top of list

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

Oracle 12c

I currently have the following three tables: Physician, Patient, and Wait_List. The Wait_List table is a bridge table to  hold patients who are waiting on individual doctors.

I would like to track priority for each of these patients in a way other than the date they entered the wait list. For instance, if a given doctor is waiting on 3 patients each of these patients are assigned a value of 1-3 in their Priority field.

The issue I am having is figuring out how I would begin to write the procedure to enter a fourth patient who is to have a priority higher than 4, for instance a priority of 1. I understand that the procedure would require each of the 3 current patients' priorities to be pushed down in value.

Any guidance to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: This part does not make sense to me, please clarify/correct: *enter a fourth patient who is to have a priority higher than 4, for instance a priority of 1*

Comment: the wait_list table will have the following three columns: physicianID, patientID, Priority. Priority will be an incremented number that is unique for each instance of (PhysicianID, PatientID). 

In the scenario above, we have a physician who is waited on by 3 patients. Each of these patients have been assigned a number based on priority (1, 2, or 3). A fourth patient comes in and it was decided for this patient to be put ahead of the previous 3 patients. Thus, this fourth patient will have a priority of 1 and the previous three patients will have priorities of 2,3, and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure will insert values into the wait_list table and it will set the priority number to one if there are already three patients waiting for that particular physician. Just edit the column and table names

```
  create procedure insertinto_Wait_List(i_patient_name IN Patient.patient_namecolumn%TYPE, i_physician Physician.Physician_column%TYPE)
  IS
  v_max_priority NUMBER;
  BEGIN
  select max(prioritynumber_column) into v_max_priority from Wait_List where Physician_column = i_physician;
  if v_max_priority > 2 THEN
  update Wait_List set prioritynumber_column = prioritynumber_column + 1 where Physician_column = i_physician;
  insert into Wait_List (prioritynumber_column, patient_namecolumn, Physician_column) values (1,i_patient_name, i_physician);
  else
  insert into Wait_List (prioritynumber_column, patient_namecolumn, Physician_column) values (v_max_priority + 1,i_patient_name, i_physician);
  end if;
  end;
```

Comment: This got me where I needed to go!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There could be better answers using advanced PL/SQL. But using unique constraint is what comes to my mind. When you create the table wait_list, add the following [unique constraint](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php) to create statement:

```
CONSTRAINT priority_unique UNIQUE (prioritynumber_column, Physician_column)
```

Then the procedure, can use the exception as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert_wait_list(i_priority IN wait_list.prioritynumber_column%TYPE, i_patient_name IN Patient.patient_namecolumn%TYPE, i_physician Physician.Physician_column%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Wait_List (prioritynumber_column, patient_namecolumn, Physician_column) values (i_priority,i_patient_name, i_physician);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
      THEN
      FOR i IN (SELECT prioritynumber_column, patient_namecolumn, Physician_column
          FROM Wait_List 
          WHERE Physician_column = i_physician 
          AND prioritynumber_column >= i_priority)
      LOOP
      UPDATE Wait_List 
      SET prioritynumber_column = prioritynumber_column + 1;
      END LOOP;
      INSERT INTO Wait_List (prioritynumber_column, patient_namecolumn, Physician_column) values (P_priority,i_patient_name, i_physician);
END proc_insert_wait_list;
```

The idea, you can set the priority you want. But if it collides with existing one, RDBMS will throw the exception [DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440135/how-to-catch-a-unique-constraint-error-in-a-pl-sql-block). Which you handle by pushing down all the existing records and then insert the priority.